# Disable or change the "Back" animation in Chrome on Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os

I am using Google Chrome OS Version 63.0.3239.140 (Official Build) (64-bit) on an Acer Chromebook 14 CB3-431.

I've noticed that while browsing in Chrome if I use two fingers to swipe to go back to the previous website an animation plays of the current page sliding off the screen and an image of the previous page shows up.

However, during this animation it can get "stuck" halfway between staying on the current page and going back to the previous page. It can also go "too far" and the previous page starts to also slide off (presumably to try to show me the page I was at 2 pages ago).

So I have to either swipe again to get the page to go away completely or swipe forward a bit to "land" on the actual page I want. All in all this "feature" is just really annoying.

Is there anyway to disable the "Back" animation or make it behave intelligently?

Here's an example of what it looks like when it's "stuck".

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A switch for this feature can be found at:

```
chrome://flags/#overscroll-history-navigation
```

Comment: Yes! Setting this flag to "Simple" is so much better.

Answer (score 0):

If Chrome is stuttering/ loads slowly, can you try disabling hardware acceleration in your Chrome Settings? Click on the Chrome menu > Settings > Show advanced settings > Scroll down to "System" > Uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available".

Any improvement?

Comment: I don't have that option (searched for "hardware" and "acceleration" in settings and couldn't find it. I don't have a "system" section under advanced settings). Also, it's not that it's stuttering or slow, it simply doesn't go back all the way and stops halfway between. Unless I swipe again to continue it just sits there halfway between the two pages. Granted I'm probably doing too "short" of a swipe, but apparently it's enough to start the animation but not finish it. I just want it to go back no matter how short or long my swipe is.